# How to convert an instance into String type in python?

Tags: python, string, instance

say class instance is `printHello` for class `Hello` 
Now when I execute below code 
`print printHello` 
The output is `"HelloPrinted"`
Now I want to compare the `printHello` with a string type and cannot achieve it because `printHello` is of type instance.
Is there a way to capture the output of `print printHello` code and use it for comparison or convert the type of `printHello` to string and I can use it for other string comparisons?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is very difficult to follow. Please add code for context.

Comment: What is your goal for comparing? If you want to see if the object is a certain type, use `isinstance(printHello, Hello)`.

Comment: How in the world did a class named 'Hello' end up so that `print printHello` results in `"HelloPrinted"`? Does `Hello` have a `__str__` or `__repr__` method? You can get the name of the class with `printHello.__class__.__name__`, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to specifically compare to strings you could do it in two different ways. First is to define the `__str__` method for your class:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, data="HelloWorld"):
        self._data = data
    def __str__(self):
        return self._data
```

Then you can compare to a string with:

```
h = Hello()
str(h) == "HelloWorld"
```

Or you could specifically use the `__eq__` special function:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, data="HelloWorld"):
        self._data = data
    def __str__(self):
        return self._data
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            return self._data == other
        else:
            # do some other kind of comparison
```

then you can do the following:

```
h = Hello()
h == "HelloWorld"
```

Answer (score 2):

A special method __repr__ should be defined in your class for this purpose:

```
class Hello:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name= name

    def __repr__(self):
        return "printHello"
```

Answer (score 1):

Either define **str** or **repr** in Hello class

More information here - [https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.**str**](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
string_value = printHello.__str__()

if string_value == "some string":
  do_whatever()
```

The `__str__()` method is used by `print` to make sense of class objects.

Comment: I got the below error 
>> AttributeError: Hello instance has no attribute '__str__'